# declaring a background image in css but background image is not appearing

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a background image to the first `<div>` on my homepage under the navbar. I am using Bootstrap 4 and a custom style.css file.

My html is:

```
  <body>



    <div id="wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
        <a href="#" id="text">
          text
        </a>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent navbar-selections">

        <div id="select-container">

            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">link</a>
                  </li>
                   <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">link</a>
                  </li>
            </ul>

        </div>

        <div id="phone-number">
        <ul>        
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">555.867.5309</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        </div>

      </div>

     </nav>

    </div> 

    <div class="index-intro">




    </div>
```

and my css is the following:

```
.index-intro {

        background: url(img.JPG);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% 100%;

    }
```

However, my background image does not appear, just a white screen with the navbar at the top. i am very confused and have tried a couple of different approaches.

For instance, if i put the image inside the div like below:

```
<div class="index-intro">

    <img src="img.jpg">


        </div>
```

It takes up the entire page and overlaps over the navbar.

And when i contain the navbar inside the div, it only makes the background image appear inside the nav and leaves the rest of the page blank.

Any ideas on how to make the background image just under the nav bar for the rest of the page?

Comment: background: url("img.JPG"); Use double quotes and make sure the image path is correct, mention the width and height of the container as the image acts as a background not an element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that your .index-intro has a width and a height, equal to the size of the image, if you want to display the entire image (Or an arbitrary size, if you only want to display a portion of it). The screen is white because you did not put anything inside the div, so it's size is zero. Try this:

```
.index-intro {
    background: url(img.JPG);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Say you wanted it to fill the remaining screen size after the navbar, is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Yeah. Set it's position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; This will make the image cover the entire viewport. Try it, and you will know what I mean. Once you have adjusted it, modify its position using the top, & bottom css properties. BUT do not put content inside this div. Instead, create another div, below it for your main content. This index-intro div should only be used to serve the image, if you set its position as absolute.